# Getting Hprof dump for other processes from application code

Tags: java, android, hprof

In my application , i have an option to capture the hprof dump. I
used

android.os.Debug.dumpHprofData (String fileName)

Initially i though the hprof data generated by the method above is for
the entire device , which is not so . The hprof data generated is only
for my process.

Now i am trying to generate hprof data for other process as well. I
need to get the Hprof dump for all the running processes from
application code.

from adb shell i tried "kill -10 " , This command will generate
the hprof file for the corresponding  process in the data/misc folder.

Now the problem is this command is working perfectly from the adb
shell prompt , but i am not able to embed the command to mycode.

My code is like

Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod 777 /data/misc")
Runtime.getRunTime().exec("kill -10 ")

No exceptions are thrown , but somehow  it is not working. The same
code above is capturing Hprof dump for my process, when i give my
process ID.

I tried with "android.os.Process.sendSignal (int pid,
android.os.Process.SIGNAL_USR1) ;" also.Getting the same problem.It is
capturing Hprof dump for my process. For other processes it is not
working.

Do we need to have any special permission to kill other process from
our process ? Or is it a built issue ? can you please suggest some
possible way to get Hprof dump for other processes from application
code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> Do we need to have any special
>   permission to kill other process from
>   our process ?

Yes, just like in any other Linux system.

> can you please suggest some possible
>   way to get Hprof dump for other
>   processes from application code?

Root your phone.

You can try to use `ActivityManager` and its `killBackgroundProcesses()` method, but I do not know if that generates the file you wish. If it does, it is a security breach, and needs to be fixed.